# Update employee database morning and evening

Tags: java, database, set, intersection

This is an abstract question I've:

I've a system where everyday morning, I get a file that has the current list of employees working in my company. At the end of the day, I get another file that has the updated list of employees. Some may have been fired, some hired. I need to update my database accordingly.

How do I do this?

My solution was: at the end of the day, store the list from the first file (the morning one) into two sets, mSet1 and mSet2. Store the list from the second file in Set eSet. So we have to remove all employees mSet1 - (mSet1 intersection eSet). We need to add all employees in eSet - (mSet1 intersection eSet). 
So, I would do :

1. Do mSet1.removeAll(eSet)
2. Delete all employee records in mSet1 from database
3. Do eSet.removeAll(mSet2)
4. Insert all records from eSet to database.

Is this correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the task? Just to keep the current list or do you need to run reports of morning to evening changes?

Comment: @PM77-1 : At the end of the day, just keep the employee table updated with current list. A naive way would be to delete all records from the table, and add all records from file 2. But that can be quite inefficient.

Comment: How many employees do you have? Below 100,000? Unless you have very slow hardware, drop and import would be fast. And it will be safe (since you do not modify the submitted data).  Do you need to run the update with other users accessing the table at the same time?

Comment: @PM77-1: Let's assume I have 100k+ and running on very slow hardware. There's no concurrent access involved. I just want to know if there's a faster way other than the one described above or a drop/import.

Comment: And my point was that you do not **need** a faster way of doing it from production perspective.  Or is just to exercise your brain?

Comment: Anyway you slice it you do not need to involve your front-end, SQL can handle it nicely.

Comment: @PM77-1 - It's an interview question actually.